# How to create a restart button for my snake game built in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var game = "play"; //This is the game variable   

$("#Restart").click(function() { //Using the buttons        
            console.log("Restart Works"); 
            gamerestart();
            ctx.fill
    });    

function gamerestart(){
        game = gamerestart;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#00008b';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
```

Used this method to make the other buttons work but restart one is not working?

Comment: What is `game`? Do you have a game that works? Why should `game = gamerestart` work? Do you really want to assign the function itself to game, or did you mean `game = "gamerestart"`? Show some actual code!

Answer (score 0):

```
function gamerestart(){
    game = gamerestart; //quotes?
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00008b';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Shouldn't it be "gamerestart"?